# Sum of data.frames ignoring some values

Tags: r

I have a data.frame (df1) of for example 200 rows and 69 columns with some NA and some values equal to 35 and another "data.frame" (df2) of 200 rows and 1 column without NA. I would like to sum the df2 to every column of df1 leaving NA when it is NA and 35 when the entry is 35 in df1. For example:

> ```
>  df1    
> Col1      Col2      Col3    
>   5        35        21     
>  NA        4         12      
>  35        1         NA       
> ....      ....      ......
>
>  df1    
> Estimates     
>   5     
>   1      
>   9       
>  ...
> ```

Desired output:

> ```
>  df1    
> Col1      Col2      Col3    
>  10        35        26     
>  NA        5         13      
>  35        10        NA       
> ....      ....      ......
> ```

What can I try next?

Comment: `df1[] <- lapply(df1, \`+\`, df2$Estimates)` or use matrices: `data.frame(as.matrix(df1) + df2$Estimates)`

Comment: but in `col2` you changed 35 to 40 (35+5)...

Comment: Sorry for the mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go,

```
#create logical matrix of df1 == 35
m1 <- df1 == 35

df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(i) i+df2$Estimates)
df1[m1] <- 35
df1
#  Col1 Col2 Col3
#1   10   35   26
#2   NA    5   13
#3   35   10   NA
```